# Function Parameters in Customizing Models in Ray RLLib

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, ray, rllib

**How severe does this issue affect your experience of using Ray?**

- High: It blocks me to complete my task.

I started using Ray RLLib (version 2.7.1) to solve a RL problem with customized environments and agents. While the envs are properly set, when I started to customize models, I am quite confused and can not proceed on.

**1. What does the parameters mean in each of the methods?**
As is in the official docs, one may customize the PyTorch model like this:

```
class MyModel(TorchModelV2, nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, obs_space, action_space, num_outputs, model_config, name):
        TorchModelV2.__init__(self, obs_space, action_space,
                              num_outputs, model_config, name)
        nn.Module.__init__(self)

        # __init__ function logic

    def forward(self, input_dict, state, seq_lens):
        # forward function logic

    def value_function(self):
         # value function logic
```

But the official docs do not tell what does it mean for each of the parameters. Where can I get the detailed explanations?

**2. How does the `_disable_preprocessor_api` act?**
What confused me most is that the `obs_space` parameter in the `__init__` method comes differently from what I have defined. Also, the `input_dict` parameter in `forward` method contains the observation `input_dict['obs']` which has the data structure unclear to me. What's more, there seems to be a discrepancy between the default behaviours described in the official docs and the behaviours appear in my case.
Let's be specific. My observation space is:

```
        operation_space = Dict({
            'a': Discrete(13),
            'b': Tuple([
                Dict({
                    'b1': Discrete(3),
                    'b2': Box(low=-10, high=10, shape=(1,), dtype=np.float64),
                    'b3': Discrete(7)
                }) for _ in range(2)
            ]),
            'c': Discrete(7)
        })
        self.observation_space = Tuple([operation_space]*10)
```

I am writing my config as this:

```
config = (
    get_trainable_cls('PPO')
    .get_default_config()
    .rl_module(_enable_rl_module_api=False)
    .training(
        model={
            "_disable_preprocessor_api": True,
            "custom_model": "my_model",
            # "custom_model_config": {
            #     "input_files": args.input_files,
            # },
        },
        _enable_learner_api=False
    )
    .environment(RLSearchEnv, env_config=RLSearchEnv_config)
    .framework("torch")
    .rollouts(num_rollout_workers=1)
    .resources(num_gpus=2)
    .experimental(_disable_preprocessor_api=True)
)
```

There are two `_disable_preprocessor_api`'s in the config, although they are explained same in the official docs, it shows up different behaviours when I set them with different values.
**Case 1.** `model={"_disable_preprocessor_api": False, ...}` with `.experimental(_disable_preprocessor_api=False)`, which is the default behaviour of RLLib and the default preprocessors are applied.
The `obs_space` is `Box(-1.0, 1.0, (420,), float32)`, which is the one-hot encoded and flattened version of my original definition. I've checked the size match.
The `input_dict['obs']` preserves the original nested structure of my observation space  (i.e. it is a 10-length list), but in each `Discrete` subspace, it is now the one-hot encoded torch.tensor with additional batch dimension:

```
>>> input_dict['obs'][0]['a'].shape 
torch.Size([32, 13])
```

**Case 2.** `model={"_disable_preprocessor_api": True, ...}` with `.experimental(_disable_preprocessor_api=False)`
The `obs_space` is `Box(-1.0, 1.0, (420,), float32)`, same as case 1.
The `input_dict['obs']` is now a torch.tensor with shape [32, 420]. I guess that it flattens the observation and prepends a batch dimension.

**Case 3.** `model={"_disable_preprocessor_api": False, ...}` with `.experimental(_disable_preprocessor_api=True)`
The `obs_space` now preserves the original nested structure, it is the same as the `self.observation_space`.
The `input_dict['obs']` preserves the original nested structure of my observation space, but different from the case 1, it does not one-hot encode the discrete space, but still add a batch dimension:

```
>>> input_dict['obs'][0]['a'].shape 
torch.Size([32])
```

**Case 4.** `model={"_disable_preprocessor_api": True, ...}` with `.experimental(_disable_preprocessor_api=True)`
The `obs_space` is the same as the `self.observation_space`.
The `input_dict['obs']` is same as the case 3.

They are too complicated to be understood, and I'm unable to continue programming if I do not figure out what does they exactly mean. It would be greatly appreciated how to use this parameters. Thanks a lot in advance.

Please refer to the cases in the problem description.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.